# Why does `std::promise::set_value` throw an error when invoked from the main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

When I run the following code,

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> p;
    p.set_value(1);
    return 0;
}
```

`std::system_error` is thrown. However, when I set the promise's value in another thread,

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> p;
    std::thread([&]{p.set_value(1);}).join();
    return 0;
}
```

everything works fine. From what I understand about `std::promise`, calling `set_value` shouldn't throw an exception unless the promise has no shared state (i.e. it's been moved from) or a value has already been assigned to it, and even then it would throw `std::future_error`, not `std::system_error`. Since there's no data race or anything of that sort, it shouldn't matter whether I call `set_value` from the thread in which I created the promise or in another thread. Is there something I'm missing?

I've tried this using both *g++* and *clang* with the same results. Specifically, when I run the code at the top, the following is output to *stderr*:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

These commands were used to compile the code at the top,

```
g++ main_thread.cpp -o main_thread -std=c++17 -g -Og
clang main_thread.cpp -o main_thread -std=c++17 -lstdc++
```

and these were used to compile the code at the bottom:

```
g++ separate_thread.cpp -o separate_thread -lpthread -std=c++17 -g -Og
clang separate_thread.cpp -o separate_thread -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -lpthread
```

Comment: Very related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141204/crash-in-stdpromiseset-value-crash.  Can't explain why no exception is thrown for the second case.

Comment: @MarekR consider [this verbatim reproduction](https://www.godbolt.org/z/1Th44r).

Comment: If you add `-stdlib=libc++` to the clang pane on godbolt, you get no error.

Comment: @NathanOliver This isn't a dupe. That poster tried to set the value of a promise that had been moved from, and that therefore had no shared state. In my case, the promise had a shared state.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold A default constructed promise also has no shared state: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise

Comment: Oh, wait.  it's empty, not has none.  Not sure anymore.

Comment: sounds fishy.  I think it should be just fine.  Can you trace into it using the debugger, perhaps breaking when an exception is thrown?  I wonder if you need some compiler options to link it properly, while using `<thread>` also happens to automatically bring it in.

Comment: It works with both gcc and clang if I compile with either `-fsanitize=address` or `-pthread` and I don't know why.

Comment: @JDługosz I traced into it with GDB for the g++ version and the exception was indeed thrown within the call to `std::promise<int>::set_value`.

Comment: I'll post an edit with the compiler options I used. I think that might help.

Comment: It might indeed require the threading library, since it needs to contain locks.  "within the call" isn't useful; what was it actually trying to do that caused the error?  Like, maybe acquire a mutex?  Note Kevin's comment above.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778085/is-stdpromise-broken-on-my-machine-using-g-mp/15794105#15794105 ?  It could be dynamic linker paths or otherwise using an old version of the standard library.

Comment: @DrewDormann The trunk versions of both compilers run well, strange. The issue itself looks really like trying to relock an already locked mutex or something similar.

Comment: Oh. When I use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, it works. I looked at the man page for `g++` and apparently the former is the correct way to link it. And @JDługosz , the backtrace is unintelligible. They're all function templates with several arguments and names spanning several lines each.

Comment: Related [Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) is part of the [Thread Support Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) so it would stand to reason that it requires enabling thread support in your compiler options (e.g. `-pthread`).

Note that `-pthread` affects the compilation as well as linkage stages. From `man g++`:

> -pthread
> Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

Comment: You would think a linker error would be thrown in that case, but I suppose it's not impossible that it wouldn't.

Comment: Edited to add why -pthread is more than just a linker option